# How do I make a list be printed as buttons in the xml file? (Android)

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to make a loop that in my main.xml creates a button for each item in the list. But I cant see a way to loop in the xml file and create more buttons that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`main.xml` can't be changed by your program, any more than your Java source files.

What are you actually trying to do? Provide UI for a list? Take a look at [ListAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html).

Comment: The ListAdapter and ListView sounds like what I need, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no loop syntax for the xml layout. If it will be dynamic you have to do it programmatically.